# git log -L and Java method parameters

Tags: git, diff

I am trying to print the history for the third method in this block:

```
   public void centerCamera(LongLat longLat, float zoom) {
      // blah
   }

   public void centerCamera(LatLng latLong) {
      // blah
   }

   public void centerCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom) {
      // blah
   }
```

I added `*.java diff=java` to my `.gitattributes` so that I could do `git log -L :centerCamera:path/to/WMMapView.java` which gives the history of the first method. But I want the history for the third one, so how do I specify the method parameters to `git log`? Getting errors like `bash: syntax error near unexpected token` and `fatal: -L parameter 'centerCamera(LatLng,float)' starting at line 1: no match`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git log -L '/public void centerCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom)/',/^}/:path/to/WMMapView.java
```

Comment: thanks, that's pretty close but I see way more methods in history than just the one that I'm interested in (even after @liam 's edit)